# Why can't I run this separate window

Tags: c#, winforms

Using c# winforms, I'm trying to make a sort of overlay. Here's what I'm testing with:

Main window has this code:

```
OverlayThread = new Thread(DisplayOrderOverlay);
OverlayThread.Start();

private void DisplayOrderOverlay(object obj)
    {
        ActiveOrderOverlay AOA = new ActiveOrderOverlay();
        AOA.StartLoop();
        AOA.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And the overlay is just a list box on a form with this code:

```
public void StartLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Random r = new Random();
            listBox1.Items.Add(r.Next().ToString());
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

I never even see the overlay, but if I pause, the loop is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AOA.StartLoop();
AOA.ShowDialog();
```

You're starting your loop and trying to show the dialog on the same thread, so until the loop finishes (it never will), `AOA.ShowDialog()` isn't called. Make the loop exit and you should see your dialog open. Or, you can also test by putting a breakpoint on the second line to see if it ever gets hit (you should have done this already).

Comment: Ah that's true, cant believe I didn't notice. But what is a safe time to call that loop? I can't call it on Overlay.OnLoad, because then it never finishes loading.

Comment: I solved my own problem right after I saw your answer. `ActiveOrderOverlay AOA = new ActiveOrderOverlay();
            AOA.Show();
            AOA.StartLoop();`

Answer (score 1):

`while (true)` loop will run forever and hence freeze you app. Normally you'd `break` of such loop on some condition to terminate the loop.

Possibly you are looking for `Timer` setup for every 500ms with handler that adds random number to a list.

Side note: check out [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) for proper creation of `Random`.